# subquery in select by attribute in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, select-by-attribute

I have a table with several fields. field A contains the same kind of values as does field B. I tried to select all points where the value in field A does not exist in anywhere field B using query builder in select by attribute.

For example

```
ID A  B
1  a  b
2  b  c
3  c  a
4  d  b
```

It should select the points with ID 4 since value d does not exist in field B.
I think I should use a subquery, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use "IN" you can use a sub query that produces a list of all B values.Try:

```
NOT A IN (SELECT B FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the subquery:

```
FieldA not in (select FieldB from tablename)
```

When using the Select By Attributes tool.

[ArcGIS Help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002t000000).

Comment: I did not know of this query before,  very interesting to know!

Comment: Be careful if/when working with versioned data in ArcSDE databases. In these cases  you need to  ensure that the data in your subquery is a versioned view - http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//006z0000000q000000. Otherwise, your query may return incorrect results.